# is there a unique measure on a local field?

Tags: measure-theory, local-fields

Suppose we consider a local field and forget about the topology for a moment and consider the set of all measures on some non-trivial $\sigma$-algebra over the field that makes the field operations measurable. Has there been any research done into the nature of this set?

Comment: Given any measure, you can always multiply it by a positive number to get another measure, so without normalizing in some way there is no uniqueness (such as with Haar measure).  Also, there is a Dirac (point) measure at each point of the local field.  Is there a purpose behind your question or is it random curiosity?

Comment: This is with regard to a project I am doing where we have formulated a notion of "building in the category of measure spaces" and I am trying to classify such buildings.

Comment: Being measurable does not depend on the measure...